# Exception not being caught at catch site

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class `Bar` which inherits from std::exception.

I'm throwing that exception

`throw new Bar(foo)`

where `foo` is a parameter which we can consider arbitrary.

But it's not being caught on my catch site:

`} catch (const Bar& ex){`

In fact, the only thing that catches it is `(...)`.

What is going on? I've been through all my compiler settings that I think are relevant. Been playing with this since 5am! Help!

Comment: You're throwing a pointer, omit the `new` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `new` from the `throw`. C++ is not Java.

```
throw Bar(foo);
```

Unless you want to catch a pointer at your "catch site"!